# Page keeps refreshing with Ajax form

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a simple form on my site with a simple jQuery Ajax call but the page keeps on refreshing. I know that the form is submitting OK but I can't get the alert to work.

```
  <script>
    $(function () {
        $('#solutionvideo').on('submit', function(e) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'http://www.domain.com/l/4882/2014-04-09/cx9c5',
                data: $('form').serialize(),
                success: function () {
                    alert('Well done');
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });     
</script>
<form action="http://www.domain.com/l/4882/2014-04-09/cx9c5" method="post"       id="solutionvideo">
<p><input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" data- validation="email" data-validation="required" data-validation-error-msg="Required field" /></span></p>
<p><input type="text" name="first" id="first" value="" placeholder="First name" data-validation="required"  data-validation-error-msg="Required field"/></p>
<p><input type="text" name="last" id="last" value="" placeholder="Last Name" data-validation="required" data-validation-error-msg="Required field"/></p>
<p><input type="text" name="company" value="" placeholder="Company" /> </p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Send" id="submit"/></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Likely lack of [noConflict wrapper](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers).

Comment: Please add [debug information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) to your **question** to make answers possible.

Comment: The noConflict wrapper resolved the issue.